# D: How to override the invariant method in a extended class?

Tags: oop, overriding, d, invariants

I am trying to create a **Liskov principle violation** example for studying purposes:

```
import std.stdio;
class Pessoa {
    string nome;
    string apelido;
    this(string nome, string apelido){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.apelido = apelido;
    } 
    invariant{
        assert(nome != apelido);
    }
}
class BoaPessoa : Pessoa {
    this(string nome, string apelido){
        super(nome, apelido);
    }
    string getNomeCompleto(){
        return this.nome ~"vulgo" ~ this.apelido;
    }
}
class MalvadaPessoa : Pessoa {
    this(string nome, string apelido){
        super(nome, apelido);
    }
    override invariant{
        assert(this.nome != "");
    }
}
void main(){
    BoaPessoa bp = new BoaPessoa("João","Joãozinho");
    MalvadaPessoa mp = new MalvadaPessoa("x", "Joãzinho");
}
```

But I was not able to override invariant on MalvadaPessoa class, I've got this error:

> main.d(25): Error: function main.MalvadaPessoa.__invariant2 cannot
>   override a non-virtual function

And without override, MalvadaPessoa has two assertions and not only one overroded

So, how to override the invariant method in a extended class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. These language features are designed to enforce the liskov principles, not violate them. Invariants must always hold, even in child classes. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant )

If you want to deliberately cheat for demonstration purposes, you could write some other method and call it manually, but the `invariant` keyword won't help you break the rules...

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks!